# Downloading Multiple Images From A Server

Tags: php, android, database, image, download

I'm making an app which has a user profile and so far I've made it so that users can pick their username, password, email, name, and a profile picture. 
The profile picture can be either taken on the spot or chosen from the phones image gallery.

I have 6 ImageView's in total, one of which is for the profile picture (they are separated in 2 rows and 3 columns). With the code that I will provide below I can only modify user's profile picture, and I can't see how I can change it so I could download all of the images(into the ImageViews) that I've uploaded without making the code unnecessarily long.

Here's the general idea of what happens: The user picks a image, the image is uploaded/posted to the server in a folder (`SERVER_ADDRESS + "uploads/"+ name + ".JPG"`), when the user then goes to the Activity the ImageView's (but right now only one ImageView) load the pictures from the "uploads/" folder on my server.

Now what I need: When the pictures are loaded/downloaded I want them to be stored on the phone. Can the Images all be downloaded at the same time, stored, and perhaps loaded into the ImageView's from there, and then deleted from the phone when the user leaves another users profile? 
I also have a ViewPager where the Images have to be loaded so that's why I don't want then downloaded every time the users goes from one tab to another in the pager.

And of course if there is a better way, please be sure to include that in the answer.
Sorry for the messy code but I'm just trying to find a way to do this correctly.

**Edit:**

I changed the DownloadImage into a public class and changed the constructor, instead of just being able to pass the String name I've added so that you can pass the ImageView which lets me load any amount of images i want. I'm going to **bold** the changes in the code. Also does anyone know a easy method of storing images on a phone in the internal storage or sd card so i can load my images from there?

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

String name;
**ImageView imageView;**

public DownloadImage(String name, **ImageView imageView**) {

    this.name = name;
    **this.imageView = imageView;**
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

    String url = ServerRequests.SERVER_ADDRESS + "pictures/" + name + ".JPG";

    try {

        URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(ServerRequests.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        connection.setReadTimeout(ServerRequests.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);


        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) connection.getContent(), null, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    super.onPostExecute(bitmap);


    if (bitmap != null) {

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }


}
```

Comment: capture image -> store -> send. If you have quota for your data usage. Sending and downloading it back will consume much more data usage than saving it in the first place.

Comment: See I never thought of that, the simplest things is what I never look into.